# jmeter header manager remove header

Tags: http-headers, jmeter

I have a large and deep test and am using jmeter 2.1.3.

I have a default http header manager at the top level and inherited for all the samplers below.

Deep in the test structure i need to make an http request and remove all the headers inherited from the parent manager.

The docs say this is achieved by creating a child manager for this sample and declaring the header with a null value, however this just sends a null value over the air and doesnt strip the header completely from the request.

Any ideas? I really dont want to create a child manager for every sample just to over come this issue as im often tweaking the values to 99% of the samples

Comment: Hi,Are you really using 2.1.3 or 2.13 , if 2.1.3 you should urgently upgrade. Regarding the null value, where did you read this in documentation ? Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Found a cool way to sort it, as i just couldn't get the header manager to do what i think its meant to from the docs. I added a BeanShell PreProcessor to the sampler  i didn't want an inherited header to be used at all with the following:

```
sampler.getHeaderManager().removeHeaderNamed("Authorization");
```

Adding this as a child will only make the script affect the current sampler and would not impact the default if it was set.

Comment: Warning: I believe this removes it from all subsequent calls too. That said, that's exactly what I needed in my case.

Comment: @RowlandB I use JMeter 3.1 and if the BeanShell PreProcessor is nested within one request, then the header removal works only for that request (at least in my case).

Comment: Definitely removes it from the map for all following tasks. I added it back again using a post processor.

Answer (score 1):

In your header manager at the top level, you could set the values as a [variable](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1932303-variables), then later change that variable in a beanshell script.

Answer (score 0):

Or else you can use 
add bean shell postprocessor add the below code

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;
sampler.getHeaderManager().remove(1);
```

for more details refer 
http://jmeterblogb.blogspot.in/